# Android .split not working correctly

Tags: java, android

Hi the code below doesn't seem to be working correctly is there something I'm doing wrong?

Basically what happens is I receive the string `prd|50126057|12bars|5` and I'm trying to split it up into three different textViews; when I run it it only shows prd in the first textView and the others don't change. Why does this happen?

I can see it working in the logs it is just not displaying it in the other textviews.

Any help is much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Also I'm sorry if this has already been answered i did do some searching on here but couldn't find anything.

```
public void messageReceived(String message) {

    String response = message;
    String[] words = response.split("\\|");
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    tv1.setText(words[0]);
    tv2.setText(words[1]);
    tv3.setText(words[2]);
    Log.e("items-->", "" + words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2]+ " " + words[3]);

    publishProgress(message);
}
```

Comment: it display in textview check my edited ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15947434/1168654

Answer (score 1):

```
 String[] words;
 String s="prd|50126057|12bars|5"; 
 words= s.split("\\|");
 for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
 {
    System.out.println("Shifted: " +words[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }` in your project. If you are using AsyncTask, you can update the UI in either `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` or `onPostExecute(Result)` method. You also calling `publishProgress(message)` method. So better you can update your UI(assign string to Textview) in either `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` or `onPostExecute(Result)` method. For eg:

```
public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,SOCKETClient> {
    @Override
    protected SOCKETClient doInBackground(String... message) {
        socketClient = new SOCKETClient(new SOCKETClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                // this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        socketClient.run();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        String response = values[0];
        String[] words = response.split("\\|");
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        tv1.setText(words[0]);
        tv2.setText(words[1]);
        tv3.setText(words[2]);
    }
}
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
String response = "abc|asd|asd|asd";
String[] words = response.split("\\|");
Log.e("items-->", "" + words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2]+ " " + words[3]);
```

o/p :

```
04-11 16:55:58.216: E/items-->(3885): abc asd asd asd
```

---

```
Edited:

String response = "abc|asd|asd|asd";

    String[] words = response.split("\\|");

   // Log.e("items-->", "" + words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2]+ " " + words[3]);

   TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

   tv.setText("" + words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2]+ " " + words[3]);
```

---

### Last Edited:

```
        String response = "abc|asd|asd|asd";

        String[] words = response.split("\\|");

        // Log.e("items-->", "" + words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2]+
        // " " + words[3]);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        tv.setText("" + words[0]);
        tv1.setText("" + words[1]);
        tv2.setText("" + words[2]);
        tv3.setText("" + words[3]);
```

[image]

Comment: I can see it working in the logs it is just not displaying it in the other textviews.

Comment: I can see your edits and yes i know it works in one textView like i explained in the top post, the problem I'm having is it wont separate it over 2 or 3 textviews. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: @user2072623: if it work with single text view. then it also work for multiple textview..

Comment: If it did do you think I would be asking the question??

Comment: @user2072623: check my last edited ans... its working. m i right??

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of your words array?

```
String test = "prd|50126057|12bars|5";
String [] words = test.split("\\|");
System.out.println(words.length);
```

Gives 4 as expected for me.

Comment: You are just printing it and not putting them into textViews here. I can't get it to split the string and show in multiple textviews.

Comment: Ok, assuming that words[1] correctly contains "50126057", what does tv2.getText() return before and after your call to tv2.setText(words[1])?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Could you log the output from tv2.getText() before and after your call to tv2.setText(words[1]) to help see what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok. Either it is not called, or a wrong string is passed to it.

I'd recommend to add logging and see what happens:

```
Log.d("~~~","@@@@ response=["+response+"]");
```

and, as others suggested, `words.length` and items.

Comment: I can see it working in the logs it is just not displaying it in the other textviews.

Answer (score -2):

```
String response = "prd|50126057|12bars|5";
String[] words = response.split("|");
Toast.makeText(mActivity, words[0]+"::"+words[1]+"::"+words[2]+"::"+words[3],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The above code is working nothing wrong in that. Just check messageReceived is being called or not.